# Wpf ItemSource Doesn't Update Visual Control

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm using MVVM model, I have a view model that holds an observable
collection of MyData.  This collection is bind to a datagrid
itemsource.  I use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and i raise
the notify event after editing a certain item of the collection.
However no update on the visual control, to inspect this I added a
converter to my datagrid itemsource,so after the event is been raised,
I get to the converter with the new collection! but still the visual
doesn't get updated, only if I scroll up and down or close and open
the control. Any ideas?

Comment: call UpdateLayout() method ?!

Comment: can you add some code, how you do this ? (It should just work)

Comment: UpdateLayout() is not somthing i can call from a view model

Comment: So i managed to solve the problem  
MyData object which is the collection data needs to implement Notify or dependency object as well,
this way- when the inner object of the collection changes it notify the WPF framework automatically.